# advanced installers 13 how to modify app.config or web.config use user input?

Tags: .net, xml, advanced-installer

now,we can contain winform and Web project in on installer project,but,advanced installers 13 how to modify app.config or web.config  use user input?
thanks

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article shows how to [import and customize a XML config file](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-import-edit-xml-file.html), so the user input is stored in it.

There is also an article that shows how to [create a custom dialog](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-dialog-editor.html) (*you need Enterprise edition*) to capture the user input.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to mark the solution as the correct answer, so that others can find it easier too